# Is the HDMI Output of the Flip MinoHD HDCP encrypted?

Tags: hdmi, hdcp, flip-mino

1.) Does anybody know if the HDMI output of the Flip MinoHD is HDCP encrypted? I want to be able to convert the output of the Flip into HD-SDI (with one of these: http://www.ensembledesigns.com/products/brighteye/be83), and if it's encrypted I'm SOL.

2.) If it is encrypted, what's up with that? Any content coming out of it is mine, and I should be able to do with it as I please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I can't see any specs that say for certain, it would be extremely unusual for a camera to copy-protect its HDMI output, given that its USB output will spit out unprotected source material. The manufacturer would have to pay extra to license HDCP for its output, with no vendor benefit. I've never heard of such a case.

Comment: That's a very good point, that it would cost the mfg more to do HDCP.

I have seen some devices that HDCP encrypt all output, regardless of copyright status, however. For example, all Playstation 3 HDMI output, even if it's a movie you made yourself, is encrypted. Of course, the PS3 also plays back Blu-Ray, so they have the HDCP license already, and it's easier (and legally safer) for them to just leave it on.

Comment: I went ahead and bought a Flip to find out if this worked. It turns out that the the Flip doesn't encrypt its output. So, a win for sanity and functionality.

Comment: Great! Hooray for sanity.

Answer (score -1):

1) Any HDMI connection is HDCP encrypted

2)This is why -

> It can protect the data from Piracy using the HDCP protocol. Basically the protocol uses a handshaking mechanism to ensure that the data is transmitted between two authentic devices.

Basically the BrightEye 83 should work as it has a HDMI port

Comment: Not every HDMI connection is HDCP, and the HDMI -> SDI converter in question explicitly doesn't work with HDCP—it can't, because to do so would break the HDCP encryption and the DMCA.